# Difference between @Qualifier and @order

Tags: spring-4

I started learning spring, i got confused in the @qualifer and @order Annotation.
My doubt is both the Annotation are used for get the particular auto wire component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Qualifier used when you have multiple beans of the same type and you want to inject particular one (specified by name)

```
@Qualifier("beanOne")
@Autowired
private beanType beanName
```

@Order used to provide sorting in annotated components.

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class RankOne implements Ranks{

}

@Component
@Order(1)
public class RankTwo implements Ranks{

}

@Component
public class Results {

    @Autowired
    private List ranks ;
}
```

ranks will have rankOne, rankTwo in sorted order.